# I get the following error in my frontend when i'm trying to access a token uri with useWeb3Contract hook of moralis using my nft smart contract

Tags: solidity-0.8.x, frontend, moralis

[image: So here I an tring to access a token uri on my smart contract but it says that it is undefined]

Smart contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract BasicNFT is ERC721 {
    string public constant TOKEN_URI = "ipfs://QmXWnjpyS5ea5jwzUrogqZtVdajNkUHBzzfDKgRbEUpgAa";
    uint256 private s_tokenCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("DOGGY", "DOG") {
        s_tokenCounter = 0;
    }

    function mintNFT() public {
        s_tokenCounter++;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, s_tokenCounter);
    }

    function getCounter() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_tokenCounter;
    }
   function tokenURI(
        uint256 /*tokenId*/
    ) public pure override returns (string memory) {
        return TOKEN_URI;
    }
}
```

Frontend:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useWeb3Contract, useMoralis } from 'react-moralis';
import nftMarketplaceAbi from '../constants/NftMarketplace.json';
import nftAbi from '../constants/BasicNft.json';
import Image from 'next/image';
export default function NFTBox({
  price,
  nftAddress,
  tokenId,
  seller,
  nftmarketplace,
  listedNfts,
}) {
  const [tokenURI, setTokenURI] = useState('');
  const { isWeb3Enabled } = useMoralis();
  const { data: nfts, runContractFunction: getTokenURI } = useWeb3Contract({
    abi: nftAbi,
    contractAddress: nftAddress,
    functionName: 'tokenURI',
    params: {
      tokenId: tokenId,
    },
  });
  console.log(nfts);
  async function updateUI() {
    const tokenURI = await getTokenURI();
    setTokenURI(tokenURI);
    console.log(`The Token URI is ${tokenURI}`);

    //get token uri
    //using the image tagnfom the tokrn uri of nextjs
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isWeb3Enabled) {
      updateUI();
    }
  }, [isWeb3Enabled]);
  return <div>{tokenURI}</div>;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hi make sure your wallet or provider is on the right chain (from your use of `enableWeb3()` or `authenticate()`) - where the contract call is run depends on this chain.

You should also use the `data` state (or `nfts` as you've named it) from the useWeb3Contract hook for the result instead of `const tokenURI = await getTokenURI()`.

Alternatively for read only functions [you can use this hook](https://github.com/MoralisWeb3/react-moralis#useapicontract) which only uses the Moralis API.

You can also post on [our forum](https://forum.moralis.io/) if you still have issues with this.